# How to increase the counter of a transaction

Tags: javascript, taquito

I am using `@taquito/taquito`.

To transfer tezos tokens from one address to another is am using below function.

```
Tezos.contract.transfer({
              to: toAddress,
              amount: amountToSend,
            });
```

I need to do continuous transaction. I am getting the error "counter is already used. need to increase the counter from my next transaction". I don't want to batch the transaction. I need to make individual transactions with waiting for previous transaction to complete.

I tried increasing the counter manually like

```
Tezos.contract.transfer({
              to: toAddress,
              amount: amountToSend,
              counter
            });
```

But it is not working. How can I increase the counter in taquito?

Answer (score 0):

You can make one transaction per block from an account.

This means you need to wait for your operation to complete before sending your next operation.

If you wait for `op.confirmation(1)` to resolve, you can then make a new transaction. Taquito will get the latest counter from the chain, so you don't need to set it manually.

Comment: For simple payments (tezos.contract.transfer), a random counter (taken from a large space of numbers) does the job. For contracts, I think you have no other option than continuously switching accounts (new InMemory signer) when you want to send multiple transactions in a block.

Comment: Is the one-transaction-per-account-per-block limitation because of the Taquito library, or is it a limitation of the Tezos blockchain itself?